# document.innerHTML not working in Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to get a user's name to pop up when they click a button. I have the user name retrieval down, however, whenever the button is pressed, the sample text "Welcome user here", never changes. The page just reloads.

```
 <button onclick="back()">Login</button>

<h3 id="welcome">*Welcome user here*</h3>

<script>

function back() {
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Welcome Back!")
}
 </script
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Welcome Back!")` ==>> `document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Welcome Back!";` (extra bracket).

Comment: Oh my.... thank you!

Comment: Huh, I changed the code, and now the sample text actually changes, however, the page just reloads again and it changes back?

Comment: Yeah, it was just a syntax problem I spotted, hence it was just a comment. You'll have to make an AJAX call if you want to get information from the server to display on the page without a reload.

Comment: Please try renaming your function and closing the script tag properly. Something's telling me your browser interprets `back()`as [`history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history).